# empty results, but how can i check why?

Tags: php

With jQuery I built some nice select boxes.

```
<fieldset>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[RED]" value="true"><label>RED</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLUE]" value="true"><label>BLUE</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLACK]" value="true"><label>BLACK</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[ORANGE]" value="true"><label>ORANGE</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[GREEN]" value="true"><label>GREEN</label></div>
</fieldset>
```

To get any result in the table on the website, I have to do this:

```
$tools = json_encode($_POST['tools']);
```

which gives back a result like so:

```
{"RED":"true","BLACK":"true"}
```

However, what I need is something like this:

Red, Black, Orange, Green, Blue

So I tried this:

```
$test = $_POST['tools'];
$result = preg_replace('/({|:|true|}|")/', '', $test);
$test2 = preg_grep('/(^RED|^BLACK|^BLUE|^ORANGE|^GREEN|^red|^black|^blue|^orange|^green)/i', $result);

$tools = json_encode($test2);
```

Now, my result in the HTML website is this:

[]

My questions now are:

1) How can I check what goes back to the HTML table before it is shown there?
2) Why is the result only [] ?

Any help is welcome.

The full code is currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <!-- deze hieronder is nodig voor touchpad enabled sliders -->
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <!-- selecteren van tools .backup.
    <script>
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
    </script>-->


    <script>
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
    </script>

  <!-- accordion -->
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
        event: "click",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false

    });
  });
  </script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical2" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount2" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical2" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
    <title>Left X Right -BrainGame</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
   <script>
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2(); </script>

 <style type="text/css">
p.label_checkbox_pair {
clear: both;
float: none;
position: relative;
}
p.label_checkbox_pair input {
left: 80px;
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
}
p.label_checkbox_pair label {
display: block;
margin-left: 90px;
width: 200px;
}
</style>


<!-- http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Beautifying-Checkboxes-Radio-Buttons-iCheck.html -->

<script src="js/icheck.js"></script>
<script>
//oud $(document).ready(function(){
  //$('input').iCheck({
    //checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
    //radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
 // 


    //increaseArea: '20%'  optional
  //});
//});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
      label = self.next(),
      label_text = label.text();

    label.remove();
    self.iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_line-blue',
      insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
    });
  });
});
</script>
    <link href="skins/line/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>

<BODY>
<br /><br />
<table HSPACE="50" CELLPADDING="20">
<tr HSPACE=50 CELLPADDING="30">
<td>
<?php 
$a=array("red","blue","black","orange","green");
$random_keys=array_rand($a,5);


$textcolours=array('red','blue','black','orange','green');
shuffle($textcolours);

echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[0]' >".$a[$random_keys[0]]."<br><br></font></right>";
echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[1]' >".$a[$random_keys[1]]."<br><br></font></right>";
echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[2]' >".$a[$random_keys[2]]."<br><br></font></right>";
echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[3]' >".$a[$random_keys[3]]."<br><br></font></rightr>";
echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[4]' >".$a[$random_keys[4]]."<br><br></font></right>";
?>
</td>




<td>

  <div class="left">

     <form class="span4" action="" method="post">

  <fieldset>

    <legend>Left X Right  BrainGame</legend>

    <p halign="right" margin="10px">Name: <input type="text" name="naam" ></p>

    <p halign="right" margin="10px">Date: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" ></p>


    <!--
    <label>Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="type">
  <option value="Nauwkeurig">Nauwkeurig</option>
  <option value="Pragmatisch">Pragmatisch</option>
</select>-->


    <!--
   <label>Core gericht: Functioneel / Technisch<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="PORTEFEUILLE"> 
<!--    <select name="core">
  <option value="Functioneel">Functioneel</option>
  <option value="Technisch">Technisch</option>
</select>
-->

    <!--
     <label>Management<span class="required">*</span></label>

    <select name="management">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
</select> -->


    <!-- <label>Aantal<span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" name="mi" placeholder="Middle Name"> -->


     <!--
     <label>Tools<span class="required">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="tools" class="input-small" placeholder="Describe tools...."> -->


    <br>
    <!--
    <br>
    <script>$('#widget').slider-vertical();</script>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Analytical:</label>
  <input name="analytisch" type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-vertical" style="height:10px; width:90%;"></div>
    <br>
    -->


    <!--
    <label>Analytisch</label>
   <label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="analytisch" id="optionsRadios1" value="Ja" checked>
  Ja
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="analytisch" id="optionsRadios2" value="Nee">
  Nee
</label> -->





<!--
<p>

  <label for="amount2">Management experience:</label>
  <input name="management" type="text" id="amount2" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-vertical2" style="height:10px; width:90%;"></div>

-->




 <br>
<!-- <label>Eneagram<span class="required">*</span></label>

<select name="eneagram">
   <option value="1 de Perfectionist">de Perfectionist</option>
   <option value="2 de Helper">de Helper</option>
   <option value="3 de Winnaar">de Winnaar</option>
   <option value="4 de Romanticus">de Romanticus</option>
   <option value="5 de Waarnemer">de Waarnemer</option>
   <option value="6 de Loyalist">de Loyalist</option>
   <option value="7 de Plannenmaker">de Plannenmaker</option>
   <option value="8 de Leider">de Leider</option>
   <option value="9 de Vredestichter">de Vredestichter</option>
</select> -->


         <?php
if(isset($_POST['getdata'])){
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','t','w');
mysql_select_db("test",$conn);

$regexp = "/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/";

$naam=$_POST['naam'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
//$type=$_POST['type'];
//$core=$_POST['core'];
//$management=$_POST['management'];


//$names = $tools; 
//$output = preg_grep('/(Andrew|John)/i', $names); 
//print_r( $output );

//
//http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#match
$test = $_POST['tools'];
$result = preg_replace('/({|:|true|}|")/', '', $test);
$test2 = preg_grep('/(^RED|^BLACK|^BLUE|^ORANGE|^GREEN|^red|^black|^blue|^orange|^green)/i', $result);

$tools = json_encode($test2);
//$tools = $_POST['tools'];
//$tools = json_encode(preg_grep('/(RED|BLACK|BLUE|ORANGE|GREEN)/i', $_POST['tools']));
//$tools = json_encode($_POST['tools']);
//$analytisch=$_POST['analytisch'];
//$eneagram=$_POST['eneagram'];

if(true == false ){
    echo "<label class='err'>All fields are required</label>";
    }

        else{
$insert="Insert into kandidaat(naam,date,tools)
 values('".$naam."','".$date."','".$tools."')";

$rs=mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<script>
<?php echo "$test2"; ?>
alert('Stop the timer!');

</script>";
<?php }
}
 ?>

  </fieldset>


<div id="accordion" style="width:90%;">
  <h3>Start...</h3>
  <div>
    <p class="label_checkbox_pair">

<!--<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="iCheck" value="true"><label for="certs">ISTQB2</label></div>-->
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[RED]" value="true"><label>RED</label></div>
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[BLUE]" value="true"><label>BLUE</label></div>
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[BLACK]" value="true"><label>BLACK</label></div>
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[ORANGE]" value="true"><label>ORANGE</label></div>
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[GREEN]" value="true"><label>GREEN</label></div>
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Part 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    <!-- zie content website https://select2.github.io/examples.html -->
    <fieldset>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[RED]" value="true"><label>RED</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLUE]" value="true"><label>BLUE</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLACK]" value="true"><label>BLACK</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[ORANGE]" value="true"><label>ORANGE</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[GREEN]" value="true"><label>GREEN</label></div>
</fieldset>
</p>
    </div>

</div>


<br/>    <button type="submit" name="getdata" class="btn">Submit</button>
<a href="toonkandidaat.php" class="btn btn-primary">Highscores</a>


</form>

   </div>
   <?php 
   function save(){


    }
   ?>
<?php
function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z&#1072;-&#1103;&#1040;-&#1071;()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
?>












</td>
</tr>
</table>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: why you used preg_grep() again on $result? you want an array(Red, Black, Orange, Green, Blue) or just a string like "Red, Black, Orange, Green, Blue"; ?